# How to check out a specific version of Eclipse's built in plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, versioning, git-checkout

I use Eclipse 4.2 Juno (Build id: I20120608-1400) and I would like to change one of its built in plugin, so I would like to checkout that, but do not know how.

The file is: `org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.103.0.v20120530-1824.jar`

I tried CVS repo that I found on eclipse site, but I cannot find this particular tag/version.
I tried Git, where I could find the version, but not `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` itself.

Could anybody tell me please how to get a specific source version of Eclipse in step by step?

Answer (score 1):

I'd not recommend using Git until it's finally migrated.

Try [This resource](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto) or [another](http://wiki.eclipse.org/SVN_Howto)

The best way to access repository is from eclipse itself.

Comment: I've already checked both of them, using Eclipse itself of course. I've posted this question after I tried everything that I could imagine. I use EGit, Tortoise Git, Built in CVS, Tortoise SVN. I need a step-by-step instruction, because maybe I am blind, but cannot figure it out how to get that specific version. Thank you!

Comment: Roman C's answer seems straightforward (but thank you for that), but I'am unable to find the right version of the code. It seems a mess for me.

Comment: If you are using CVS than you should know a sticky label of release. If using SVN then it should be a tag.

Comment: Thanks to Dani Megert on Eclipse forum: the trick is as follows: after launching Eclipse > File > Import... > Plugins and fragments dialog, you have to choose "Import as: Project with source folders" option. Further settings are straightforward. This is the correct answer to my question.

Comment: @user1640463 This is not check out from the repository.